# Recovery of a sharded Mongo cluster which has lost one shard

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, sharding, replicaset, mongodb-replica-set

Here is the topology I have running off self hosted Ubuntu machines on AWS (EC2)
MongoDB version 5.0.3

**Mongos** - 1 server
**Config** Servers (3 servers)
**Shards** (3) each is a ReplicaSet with 3 members each, therefore 9 data nodes

For various reasons, which don't seem to be in the logs, all 3 members of Shard 3 went down. Restarting the processes on these 3 members was the most obvious step, however, this was the output.

```
ubuntu@XXXXXXXX:~$ mongosh
Current Mongosh Log ID: 619aa17d4fac3c77a109b11b
Connecting to:      mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?directConnection=true&serverSelectionTimeoutMS=2000
MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
```

Eventually, one member came back, as SECONDARY, restarting the **mongod** processes on the other members seemed to cascade and kill the first member. At least so it appeared.

Following this [guide](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/reconfigure-replica-set-with-unavailable-members/), I entered **mongosh** on Shard 3, Member 1 (3-1),  I then disconnected the other members from the ReplicaSet. After this, Member one refuses to start. The process logs show this

```
ubuntu@XXXXXXX:~$ sudo systemctl status mongod
● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: signal) since Sun 2021-11-21 20:02:31 UTC; 798ms ago
       Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
    Process: 1094 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=killed, signal=ABRT)
   Main PID: 1094 (code=killed, signal=ABRT)

Nov 21 20:02:26 ip-172-31-32-42 systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.
Nov 21 20:02:31 ip-172-31-32-42 systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, code=killed, sta>
Nov 21 20:02:31 ip-172-31-32-42 systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
```

1. Is it possible to get any of these members in RS3 back up?
2. Is it possible to restore the data that has been sharded on Shard 3, of course this is only part of it, Shard 1 & Shard 2 (and their ReplicaSets are okay)

Comment: First, check log file of that node (check path from /etc/mongod.conf) what is the real reason why mongod didn't start. I guess that one of needed files are not owned my mongod, probably it's owner by root. Fix ownership error and try to start again.

Comment: Yes, perms are mongodb:mongodb
I did tail the logs...

{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-21T19:20:13.933+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"OplogApplier-0","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7F5618AEC293","b":"7F56189CA000","o":"122293","s":"clone","s+":"43"}}}

The strange bit is the ABRT signal, with 

Nov 22 13:59:06 ip-172-31-32-42 systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.
Nov 22 13:59:11 ip-172-31-32-42 systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited>
Nov 22 13:59:11 ip-172-31-32-42 systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result >

No clear message (to me at least)

Comment: Perhaps I could simplify my query with, what is the plan when an entire shard fails and cannot be recovered? 
Do the config servers have refs to these lost chunks?
I am able to isolate one member from the ReplicaSet and mongodump them, will be possible to rs.initialize() and reuse the data?.. will the other 2 shards work seamlessly with a reinitialized shard?
Lots of q's :)

Comment: When there is ABRT signal little after "systemctl start", problem is normally that, that mongod cannot create PID file. No PID file, and systemd things that process is not running as daemon and give ABRT signal to that process... You can always try to start mongod as root. #>mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf  but after that you need to "clean up", by fixing ownership back to mongod user (data directory, PID file, log file...)

Comment: During years, I have seen same kind of problems that mongod don't start... And always it has been problem with ownership of files (data, pid, log...). Answer is always found from the log, just read it from the moment when mongod tries to start and finally fail at some point... But reason for the fail is always in log file. IF there is no log file, then problem is that, that mongod couldn't write that log file... ;-)